# VBA como procurar o nome especifico de uma planilha e imputar dados nela

Tags: vba

Pessoal tenho uma lista na plan("Cadastro").range("H2:H10")

Tenho Dados             na plan("Tratado").range("A2":"Q1862")

quero procurar o nome na lista da plan("Cadastro").range("H2:H10"), na plan("Tratado").range("A2").value e quando achar, gostaria que toda a linha  aonde esse nome foi achado, fosse copiada para a planilha cujo nome eu já criei que é igual ao nome procurado, e quando o nome for igual vai populando e quando for diferente, procura a planilha de mesmo nome e popula ela tbm assim por diante.

Eu sei os conceito básicos de procura, mas não sei como procurar por nomes de planilhas específicas ao qual será igual ao nome armazenado em uma variavel.

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Se as duas planilhas estiverem abertas você pode usar um

```
Workbooks("Nome da planilha.xlsx").Worksheets("Nome da Planilha").Cells(x,y)
```

pra procurar dentro da outra, claro, você terá de usar outras estruturas, mas essa linha você verifica.

Comment: joia muito obrigado meu amigo!